# File not relocating correctly c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have my program setup to rename and store a file according to checkbox input. I used another stackoverflow post for my template. Only problem is when I tried setting it up for sub-folders, it never puts it in the correct folder. I have a label folder with two sub folders called L-Labels and B-Labels. The user checks which label type it is and the file gets renamed and placed in the according sub-folder. When I used breakpoint my variables are getting the correct value so I don't see what's wrong I have provided my variables and code for relocating the file. What is causing this to not put it in my sub-folder?

Varibales:

```
string oldPath = lblBrowseName.Text;
string newpathB = @"C:\Users\Public\Labels\B_Labels";
string newpathL = @"C:\Users\Public\Labels\L_Labels";
```

Method:

```
if (rChkBoxBizerba.Checked == true)
{
string newFileName = rtxtBoxNewVersion.Text;
FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo(oldPath);
if (f1.Exists)
{
if (!Directory.Exists(newpathB))
{
Directory.CreateDirectory(newpathB);
}
f1.CopyTo(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", newpathB, newFileName, f1.Extension));
if (System.IO.File.Exists(lblBrowseName.Text))
System.IO.File.Delete(lblBrowseName.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is the problem:

```
f1.CopyTo(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", newpathB, newFileName, f1.Extension));
```

You declare your path but it doesn't have a trailing directory separator, so when you combine all the parts, as above, the actual result is invalid.

You really should use [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to combine parts of paths together, this uses the correct directory separator and makes additional checks.

Try something like this:

```
// Build actual filename
string filename = String.Format("{0}{1}",newFileName, f1.Extension));

// Now build the full path (directory + filename)
string full_path = Path.Combine(newpathB,filename);

// Copy file
f1.CopyTo(full_path);
```

Comment: So instad of f1.Copyto use Path.Combine()?

Comment: No you'd still use `CopyTo` but your destination filename is incorrect currently.

Comment: Got you now! Thank you for the clarification I am about to try that.